# Wrong generic return type

Tags: java, generics

Let me show my quick example:

```
public class Main {

    public static abstract class Food { 
    }

    public static abstract class Fruit extends Food {
        public String getJuice(){
            return "juice";
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Container<T extends Food> {
        private T food;
        public final T get(){
            return food;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Crate<T extends Fruit> extends Container<T> {
    }

    public static void Bar(Crate crate) {
        Food  f  = crate.get(); //compiles fine
      //Fruit f2 = crate.get(); //can't compile
    }                           
}
```

When given a raw type, `crate.get()` returns `Food` instead of `Fruit`

- note: `Crate` is declared as `Crate<T extends Fruit> extends Container<T>` so `Crate<Food>` is forbidden.

I am just curious: why does the method `T get()` not return `Fruit`? Why is `Crate<Fruit>` required?

Comment: You cannot do `Crate<Food>` because you've declared that `Crate<T extends Fruit>`. `Food` does not extend `Fruit`.

Comment: Well, that's obvious. Just looks to me as compiler does not know what does he want exactly. Saying that `crate` is `Crate<Food>` and is not simultaneously

Comment: @TomatoMato Please explain your question a bit clearly. Till now I haven't understood what your question really is?

Comment: Using raw types loses some type-safety. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Not sure *why* exactly the compiler complains about this, but you can easily "fix" this. Use something like `Bar(Crate<? extends Fruit> crate)` to keep type safety without loss of generality.

Comment: I see what you are asking. I edited the question to attempt to clarify. It seems that in the presence of a raw type, erasure of `Container` is used instead of erasure of `Crate`. That is a little wonky and seems to do with the fact that `get` is declared on `Container`. For example either declaring the type of `crate` as `Crate<?>` or overriding `get` on `Crate` works. This is probably in the spec somewhere.

Comment: Well I can't find anything in the spec about this. `:)` Only a few hints that something like this could happen. If anyone wants to pick up where I left off, generics are roughly sections 4.4-4.9 and then scattered about elsewhere. I did JLS hunting yesterday too.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because `get` is declared by `Container`. When using the raw type `Crate`, which has the effect of applying [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to all of its (inherited) methods, the signature of `public T get()` is erased to `public Food get()`, because `T` has an upper bound of `Food` *in its declaring class*.

While `Crate` narrows the upper bound of `T`, which happens to be the return type of `get`, it doesn't override that method. If that were the case, you would see different behavior:

```
public static abstract class Container<T extends Food> {
    private T food;
    public T get() {
        return food;
    }
}

public static abstract class Crate<T extends Fruit> extends Container<T> {

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return super.get();
    }
}

public static void bar(Crate crate) {
    Food  f  = crate.get(); // compiles fine
    Fruit f2 = crate.get(); // also compiles
}
```

Now, `public T get()` is erased to `public Fruit get()`, since it has been redeclared in a class where `T` has an upper bound of `Fruit`.